Missing HSTS Header on Azure App Service Java
I have a Java 8 Spring Boot application with Embedded Web Server deployed as Azure App Service. The application is available under a standard domain for Azure App Services - <myapp>.azurewebsites.net. My application adds HSTS (Strict-Transport-Security) header to it's HTTP responses. I verified that by issuing curl command from App Service SSH. From SSH inside App Service, I installed curl, and when I issue a request I can see my Strict-Transport-Security header and also my custom X-Custom-Header which is returned by my application:
> curl http://0.0.0.0/test/debug -v 
< HTTP/1.1 200 
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 
< X-Custom-Header: custom-value
< ...other headers...

However, when I try to do the same through <myapp>.azurewebsites.net domain, the Strict-Transport-Security header is missing:
> curl https://<myapp>.azurewebsites.net/test/debug -v 
< HTTP/1.1 200 
< X-Custom-Header: custom-value
< ...other headers visible but no Strict-Transport-Security... 

How can I add Strict-Transport-Security header to responses when reaching my App Service API through public <myapp>.azurewebsites.net domain?
The application itself sets it correctly, as I proved by issuing curl command through App Service SSH, yet the header get removed when application is reached through public <myapp>.azurewebsites.net domain.
Here's the JAX-RS controller I use to debug this issue, which always adds Strict-Transport-Security header and X-Custom-Header for debugging purposes:
import javax.ws.rs.*
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response


@Path("/test")
class DebugResource {
    @GET
    @Path("/debug")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    fun debug(): Response {
        return Response.ok("test")
            .header("Strict-Transport-Security", "max-age=31536000")
            .header("X-Custom-Header", "custom-value")
            .build()
    }
}


please share your code that you've tried

Remember that Strict-Transport-Security is ignored by the browsers when set over HTTP, Strict-Transport-Security is only valid and used by the browsers if set over HTTPS.

@Rames Try using Spring MVC annotations instead of JAX-RS it worked for me both locally and in production.

@ToreNestenius yes I know that, I just wanted to make sure that header is returned by the application no matter what - and yet it is still missing through my Azure App Service URL, regardless of whether I use HTTPS or HTTP.

I got the same issue when I tried your code, it's because
you're using JAX-RS annotations instead of Spring MVC annotations.Spring Boot does not recognize JAX-RS by default.
Refer this doc for better understanding about Spring MVC annotations.
I've modified your code to the following to correctly retrieve the headers.
DebugResource.kt:
package com.example.demoweb  
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse  
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping  
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping  
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController   
@RestController  
@RequestMapping("/test")  
class DebugResource {    
    @GetMapping("/debug")  
    fun debug(response: HttpServletResponse): String {  
        response.addHeader("Strict-Transport-Security", "max-age=31536000")  
        response.addHeader("X-Custom-Header", "custom-value")  
        return "test"  
  }  
}

Local output:


Output after deployment:



Thank you for your answer. You can use JAX-RS with Spring Boot: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/how-to/jersey.html and that what I have to do due to the nature of that application, which doesn't seem relevant to my problem.
My application works correctly when queried through localhost, which does prove that it adds that header correctly.

Thank you for your feedback, I'll try and let you know.
